# Needed to rename exe file to make it functional

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, devexpress, exe

We have in-house built windows application. From last few months we are facing a quite strange issue. Lot of our end users complaint that application is not opening. As a quick turn around we found that if we rename its exe file let say Application.exe to ApplicationRename.exe then it starts working but after some (random) days it again stops and we again need to rename it to make it work. Found no solution on internet. It is developer in VB.net using DevExpress.

Here is Windows Event Log

```
Faulting application name: ALJALALI POS2.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x621a1e64
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1566, time stamp: 0x0833f2d4
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x0000000000034f69
Faulting process id: 0x7f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d838263abd0bf6
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ALJALALI POS2.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: d179b612-d280-474b-a07f-aeb90862ba7b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Anti-virus issue? Have you checked the customers anti-virus logs?

Comment: Did it start working again if you renamed back to the original name the second time? You should have your users check the Windows event log. If they can, temporarily disabling antivirus tools while testing may help too, as implied above.

Comment: @john No. Once rename, even if we rename to original it wouldn't work.

Comment: Does your app perhaps use a webview control?

Comment: No. It is not using any webview

Comment: The error should be `STATUS_FATAL_USER_CALLBACK_EXCEPTION`, the executable file renaming thing is *obscure* -- This breaking exception in the executable loader could be caused when dereferencing a null pointer, an early thread that sets a Hook, or a thread that fails to unhook a Hook previously set (should happen later, though). Could also be generated by an instance of Internet Explorer (initialized by, e.g., a WebBrowser Control). The exe name comes into play if you enabled IE's advanced features via Registry, which requires the executable name -- Not simple to decipher with this information

Comment: It could also happen because of bitness incompatibility when loading a module -- The *work for some days after renaming* for *lots of users* thing isn't something that, personally, I've seen before. Can your app generate some form of logging before it crashes? Or is not actually loaded when this happens?

Comment: If you restart the system, can you use the old name again?

Comment: Once renamed i can not use the original name. Everytime i have to use a different name.

Comment: Someone asks above if i use webview. So basically i am not using web view but there is a method which checks for Software Version each time user opens the application. It try to reads a .txt file and compare the software version. Could it be the reason that somehow it is unable to communicate properly??

Comment: Just to clarify (and which should probably be in the question itself): You can't reuse *any* old name (even from a few renames ago), even if you turn the power off and on again?

Comment: No, we can not use old name.